# PHP: Emailing HTML Body of PHP Template file

Tags: php, email, fopen, fread

I'm currently using PHP's mail() function to email the HTML Body of another PHP file using concatenation.

This is currently working fine, however, I would prefer the script to simply get the parsed HTML Body rather than using the concatenation method.

I've read a few incomplete forum posts regarding using fopen() and fread() but had no luck myself.
Any output I have got to work has not parsed the PHP within the file.

Is there a function available that can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
ob_start();
require 'some_script.php';
$html = ob_get_clean();
```

and then you have the output of the script.

If you need to call a URL, you can do this with cURL or alternatively you can use fopen()/fread() with a URL if that option is enabled in your PHP setup. I think the option is called allow_url_fopen or something similar.

```
$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "r");
$output = fread($bundle, 20000);
```

Comment: Using output buffering is definitely the best way to go if it's on your own server... Less overhead and memory usage than a combination of fopen/fread.

Comment: Just wanted to point out that ob_start() can accept a callback argument, which may save you a few lines of code.